# How to merge results of nested scrapy requests into a single item?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a url that has a bunch of universities. For every **university**, there is a link to a list of **scholarships** that is provided by the **university**.  Inside this link (that contains a list of scholarships), there is a link to a detailed information on every such scholarship.

I am trying to yield final items like:

```json
{
name: 'universityA',
scholarships: [
    {
        name: 'sch_A',
        other_fields: other_values
    },
    {
        name: 'sch_B',
        other_fields: other_values
    }
]

},
{
name: 'universityB',
...
}
```

I have tried passing the meta attribute like:

`yield response.follow(url=sch_A_detail_url, callback=self.parse_2, meta={item: uni_item_A})`

This is my final code structure:

```
import scrapy

class UniversityItem(scrapy.Item):
    uni = scrapy.Field()
    scholarships = scrapy.Field()

class university_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test_scholarship_spider"
    start_urls = [
        "https://search.studyaustralia.gov.au/scholarship/search-results.html?pageno=1",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for div in response.css("div.sr_p.brd_btm"):
            university_item = UniversityItem()
            university_item["scholarships"] = []
            uni_name = div.css("h2 a::text").get()
            university_item['uni'] = uni_name
            full_scholarship_detail_url = div.xpath('.//div[@class="rs_cnt"]/a/@href').get()
            if full_scholarship_detail_url:
                yield response.follow(url=full_scholarship_detail_url, callback=self.parse_all_scholarships, meta={ "uni_item": university_item })
            else:
                pass
            
            yield university_item
            
    
    def parse_all_scholarships(self, response):
        for div in response.css('div.rs_cnt'):
            scholarship_detail = div.css('h3 a::attr(href)').get()
            new_scholarship = {}
            resp_meta = response.request.meta
            resp_meta["scholarship_obj"] = new_scholarship

            yield response.follow(url=scholarship_detail, callback=self.parse_scholarship_detail, meta=resp_meta)

    
    def parse_scholarship_detail(self, response):
        university_item = response.request.meta['uni_item']
        scholarship_obj = response.request.meta['scholarship_obj']
        scholarship_obj['eligibility_requirements'] = "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors."
        scholarship_obj['application_process'] = "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
        university_item['scholarships'].append(scholarship_obj)
        yield university_item
```

But instead of my expected result which is a single instance of univesityA, universityB... and them containing a final list of their related scholarships, I get multiple instances of universityA, universityB,... with increasing number of provided scholarships, probably due to yielding every item in the method `parse_scholarship_detail`.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Please create a [mre].

Comment: @Alexander thanks for your response. I have edited my question so that viewers can easily replicate my issue.

Comment: Sorry just saw your comment... did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating items as item class objects You can `yield` items as dictionaries as mentioned on https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#item-types

Usage of item class objects(or similar) makes sense **only** if You have many (50, 100 more) spiders in scrapy project where expected to return the same type of items with strict predefined structure.

By returning items as `dict` dictionaries You can define output in nearly any.. nested complexity.

so following codelines inside spider `parse` method:

```
yield {
name: 'universityA',
scholarships: [
    {
        name: 'sch_A',
        other_fields: other_values
    },
    {
        name: 'sch_B',
        other_fields: other_values
    }
]

},
{
name: 'universityB',
}
```

are valid.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations what you can do is collect all of the urls from the `parse_all_scholarships` method into a list or collection of some sort, and instead of firing off a request for each of the urls in a for loop, what you can do create your item for the current university and assign the `urn` and then pop off just one of the links in your list of urls, send it in a request with the `parse_scholarship_details` method as the callback and pass along the item and the remaining list of urls in the `cb_kwargs` parameter.

Then inside of the `parse_scholarship_details` method you can collect all the necessary information for that specific scholarship. Add the info to the item you passed in the cb_kwargs, and then pop another url off the list and duplicate the same request you passed in the `parse_all_scholarships` method with the same item and remaining urls.

This will create a chain of requests for each of the scholarship pages which you will one by one add to your scholarship item.  Then you can add an if statement at the end that checks if the list of urls is empty and if it is then and only then should you yield the Scholarship Item.

For example:

```py
import scrapy

class UniversityItem(scrapy.Item):
    uni = scrapy.Field()
    scholarships = scrapy.Field()

class university_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test_scholarship_spider"
    start_urls = [
        "https://search.studyaustralia.gov.au/scholarship/search-results.html?pageno=1",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for div in response.css("div.sr_p.brd_btm"):
            full_scholarship_detail_url = div.xpath('.//div[@class="rs_cnt"]/a/@href').get()
            if full_scholarship_detail_url:
                uni_name = div.css("h2 a::text").get()
                yield response.follow(url=full_scholarship_detail_url, callback=self.parse_all_scholarships, cb_kwargs={"uni": uni_name})


    def parse_all_scholarships(self, response, uni=None):
        links = [link for link in response.xpath("//div/h3/a/@href").getall()]
        item = UniversityItem(uni=uni, scholarships=[])
        yield response.follow(url=links.pop(), callback=self.parse_scholarship_detail, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "links": links})


    def parse_scholarship_detail(self, response, item=None, links=None):
        scholarship = {"name": response.css('h1::text').get()}
        scholarship['eligibility_requirements'] = "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors."
        scholarship['application_process'] = "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
        item["scholarships"].append(scholarship)
        if len(links) > 0:
            yield response.follow(url=links.pop(), callback=self.parse_scholarship_detail, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "links": links})
        else:
            yield item
```

Partial Output:

```json
  {
    "uni": "Deakin College",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "Deakin College International Scholarship - Vietnam",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Deakin College International Scholarship - China, Korea and Japan",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Deakin College International Scholarships",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uni": "Melbourne Polytechnic",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "International Online Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "International Higher Education Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Pathway to Victoria Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uni": "Griffith College",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "Diploma of Health Care Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Welcome to Queensland Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Accommodation Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uni": "Charles Darwin University",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "Australia Awards",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Menzies International Academic Support Package",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "2023 CDU International College Pathway Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "CDU Global Merit Scholarship 2023-2024",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Dili International School Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Vice-Chancellor\u2019s International High Achievers Scholarships (VCIHAS)",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uni": "James Cook University",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "Tom and Dorothy Cook Scholarships in Public Health and Tropical Medicine",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "International Merit Stipend",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "International Excellence Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "JCU Postgraduate Research Scholarships",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "JCU Vice Chancellor's International Student Scholarship",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "HEB Memorial Bursary",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "John and Janice King Bursary",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "uni": "Western Sydney University",
    "scholarships": [
      {
        "name": "Vice-Chancellor's Academic Excellence Undergraduate Scholarships",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Western Sydney International Scholarships \u2013 Undergraduate",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "China Scholarship Council Research Scholarships",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Vice-Chancellor's Academic Excellence Postgraduate Scholarships",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      },
      {
        "name": "Western Sydney International Scholarships \u2013 Postgraduate",
        "eligibility_requirements": "multiple requirements that will be scrapped using selectors.",
        "application_process": "multiple processes that will be scrapped using selectors."
      }
    ]
  },
```